# Collagen digestion

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, enzymes

As far as I know, pepsin is used very often in collagen solutions extraction. Since it only cleaves the telopeptides and leaves the triple helix chains of the collagen intact. I was wondering if there is any other enzyme that can do similar work to extract collagen?